# RxThreadFactory doesn't implement interface concurrent

Tags: java, rx-java

When calling

```
Observable.interval(10, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

in my target environment (works great on standard JVM) I'm getting:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class
>   rx.internal.util.RxThreadFactory does not implement the requested
>   interface java.util.concurrent.ThreadFactory  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:610)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.addWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:924)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.ensurePrestart(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1590)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.delayedExecute(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:333)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:594)
>     at
>   rx.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler$CachedWorkerPool.(CachedThreadScheduler.java:62)
>     at
>   rx.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler.start(CachedThreadScheduler.java:150)
>     at
>   rx.schedulers.CachedThreadScheduler.(CachedThreadScheduler.java:145)
>     at rx.schedulers.Schedulers.(Schedulers.java:48)  at
>   rx.schedulers.Schedulers.(Schedulers.java:34)     at
>   rx.Observable.interval(Observable.java:1293)

What does it mean? What can I do about it?

P.S.: I'm using proguard on final jar. Could it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at your error in the Java API it's a JVM runtime check thingy that checks if the classes dependable on the current executing method have been changed since last executed.

Just try stopping all processes executing (shut everything down). Save, clear cache and recompile everything and then try running it again so everything is on the same page.

Comment: Cleaned build env, cleaned target env. Still the same. Is it possible that this interface was removed by proguard?

Comment: Is there a way to try running it without proguard?

Comment: Indeed, there is and it works (although the jar is ridiculously big). What should I add to my proguard properties then?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what properties to use. Maybe someone else can shed light on this issue?